# Android, change only clicked color of a button

Tags: android, button, colors, pressed

I would like to change the default orange color that appears when someone press an Android button. I have done many searches but all I found was the use of `selectors`.
I understand the principle, but I don't want to modify the grey aspect of the normal button (not pressed). But using `selectors` force to define all characteristics of all aspects (pressed or not).

I don't know how to obtain the default aspect of buttons in the light theme, so can anyone tell me where I can find the original parameters of the light `theme` or at least give me another means to simply change the color of the button when clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the Android's selector into your project, the one that Android sets it by default to buttons, and modify only the state when the button is pressed by just changing one single drawable.

You could find the file in `\android-sdk\platforms\android-10\data\res\drawable\btn_default.xml`

Comment: really all my thanks !!! I a m really stupid, i should have wonder how the emulator of eclipse can display button without drawables. I will use the 9patch of a normal button. i was searching for 3 hours !! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry bro...........
i guess only selector will help you......
You must go with selector.....
and selector are reusable xmls you can use in all buttons.....:)
You can refer below link.
:)
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList

Comment: if i could find the originals drawables it would not be a problem

Comment: no problem, i discovered that i just have to put these in background with android:background, its just a special type of png, but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution to this problem, but did not succeed.
Maybe this will help:
[How to modify the default button state in Android without affecting the pressed and selected states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859144/how-to-modify-the-default-button-state-in-android-without-affecting-the-pressed)

[Standard Android Button with a different color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521640/standard-android-button-with-a-different-color)

Comment: Thanks guy but it does exactly the contrary xD. Thanks for trying.